# Getting the orientation of a PDF that has been read in through iText

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext, orientation

I am reading in a PDF through iText. How can I check to see if the orientation of the first page is in landscape or portrait mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`getPageRotation()`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html#getPageRotation%28int%29) combined with [`getPageSize()`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html#getPageSize%28int%29)

Comment: And read this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383669/itext-setrotatecontentsfalse-strange-behaviour-on-landscape-pdfs/6415326#6415326

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but getpagerotation doesn't work because the initial rotation of a page is 0 whether it is landscape or portrait.

Comment: You need to combine the two, first check if it rotated then check the size. You can calculate the orientation from the size.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using this and it seems to work well.

```
Rectangle rectangle = pdfReader.getPageSizeWithRotation(pageNumber);

if(rectangle.getHeight() >= rectangle.getWidth())
    return PageFormat.PORTRAIT;
else
    return PageFormat.LANDSCAPE;
```